# Looping through multiple pages python + beautiful soup

Tags: python, pyqt4

EDIT* Repasted the code for correct formatting. Thanks for the tip!

I'm trying to scrape a website with multiple pages. I'm attempting to use a loop to change the url and print out. The first page works, the loop enter the second loop and I see the print of page2 but I don't get any output and I seem to enter a loop that doesn't die. Any ideas where I am going wrong here?

```
import sys
from PyQt4.QtGui import *
from PyQt4.QtCore import *
from PyQt4.QtWebKit import *
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

s = list("https://games.crossfit.com/leaderboard?competition=1&year=2017&division=2&scaled=0&sort=0&fittest=1&fittest1=0&occupation=0&page=1")
for num in range(1,3):
    nums = str(num)
    s[129] =(nums)
    varurl = ''.join(s)
    print (varurl)


    class Render(QWebPage):
        def __init__(self, url):
            self.app = QApplication(sys.argv)
            QWebPage.__init__(self)
            self.loadFinished.connect(self._loadFinished)
            self.mainFrame().load(QUrl(url))
            self.app.exec_()

        def _loadFinished(self, result):
            self.frame = self.mainFrame()
            self.app.quit()

    url = varurl
    r = Render(url)
    html = r.frame.toHtml()


    soup = BeautifulSoup(html)
    for divtag in soup.find_all('div', {'id':'containerOverlay'}):
        for divtag2 in divtag.find_all('div',{'id':'leaderboard'}):
            for ultag in divtag2.find_all('ul', {'class': 'scores'}):
                for litag in ultag.find_all('li'):
                    print (litag.text)
```

UPDATE #1
I took tripleee's suggestion(Thanks!) I added a print to see where I was in the loop to see the url changing. The loop never prints the second URL and we seem to enter an infinite loop of nothingness.

```
baseurl = ("https://games.crossfit.com/leaderboard?competition=1&year=2017&division=2&scaled=0&sort=0&fittest=1&fittest1=0&occupation=0")
urls = ['{0}&page={1}'.format(baseurl, page) for page in range(1,3)]

for url in urls:
    r = Render(url)
    html = r.frame.toHtml()
    print (url)

    soup = BeautifulSoup(html)
    for divtag in soup.find_all('div', {'id':'containerOverlay'}):
        for divtag2 in divtag.find_all('div',{'id':'leaderboard'}):
            for ultag in divtag2.find_all('ul', {'class': 'scores'}):
                for litag in ultag.find_all('li'):
                    print (litag.text)
```

UPDATE #2
Rewrote using a few tips from around the internet. Same issue exists the last loop through urls works. However the scrape section doesn't seem to happen for loop length >2..

```
import sys
from PyQt4.QtCore import *
from PyQt4.QtGui import *
from PyQt4.QtWebKit import *
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

class Render(QWebPage):  
  def __init__(self, urls, cb):
    self.app = QApplication(sys.argv)  
    QWebPage.__init__(self)  
    self.loadFinished.connect(self._loadFinished)  
    self.urls = urls  
    self.cb = cb
    self.crawl()  
    self.app.exec_()  

  def crawl(self):  
    if self.urls:  
      url = self.urls.pop(0)  
      print ('Downloading', url)  
      self.mainFrame().load(QUrl(url))  
    else:  
      self.app.quit()  

  def _loadFinished(self, result):  
    frame = self.mainFrame()  
    url = str(frame.url().toString())  
    html = frame.toHtml()  
    self.cb(url, html)
    self.crawl()  


def scrape(url, html):
    pass
    soup = BeautifulSoup(html)
    for divtag in soup.find_all('div', {'id':'containerOverlay'}):
        for divtag2 in divtag.find_all('div',{'id':'leaderboard'}):
            for ultag in divtag2.find_all('ul', {'class': 'scores'}):
                for litag in ultag.find_all('li'):
                    score = litag.text
                    filename='file2.txt'
                    with open(filename,'a',encoding='utf-8') as out:
                        out.write(score + "\n")
    print (len(html))


baseurl = ("https://games.crossfit.com/leaderboard?competition=1&year=2017&division=2&scaled=0&sort=0&fittest=1&fittest1=0&occupation=0")
urls = ['{0}&page={1}'.format(baseurl, page) for page in range(1,3)]
r = Render(urls, cb=scrape)
```

Comment: Your code is syntactically incorrect because of poor formatting. Please fix it before we can make sense out of it. At the moment, I do not see how you download HTML and construct BS in a loop. Both actions are executed only once.

Comment: Your current code has syntax error because of indentation issues.  Please make sure you copy+paste the code *exactly* (hint: paste, then select the pasted code and type ctrl-K to format it as code).  Also, perhaps you want to look at the guidance for how to create a [mcve].

Comment: Sorry, I fixed the formatting on the code.

Answer (score 0):

I think your loop has indentation problem so when it enters the for loop there isn't anything inside.

```
for num in range(1,3):
   nums = str(num)
   s[129] =(nums)
   varurl = ''.join(s)
   print (varurl)
```

Try this. I think this will work.

Comment: This prints two URLs but that doesn't fix the other problem which is that the code doesn't seem to be using the generated URL before overwriting the value.  Also, the code to replace a part of the URL is kind of hacky.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion but the initial paste was formatted incorrectly. The loop is as described.

Answer (score 0):

You should probably be generating a list of URLs and then looping over that.

```
baseurl = "https://games.crossfit.com/leaderboard?competition=1&" \
    "year=2017&division=2&scaled=0&sort=0&fittest=1&fittest1=0&occupation=0"
urls = ['{0}&page={1}'.format(baseurl, page) for page in range(1,3)]

for url in urls:
    r = Render(url)
    html = r.frame.toHtml()
    # ... etc
```

If you are new to list comprehensions, the `urls` assignment could be written out in longhand as

```
urls = []
for page in range(1,3):
    pageurl = '{0}&page={1}'.format(baseurl, page)
    urls.append(pageurl)
```

Then of course, keeping the list of URLs in memory is unnecessary and potentially a problem if you plan to loop over many pages.

```
for page in range(1,3):
    pageurl = '{0}&page={1}'.format(baseurl, page)
    r = Render(pageurl)
    html = r.frame.toHtml()
    # ... etc
```

Comment: I understand where you're going with this, way cleaner than my attempt, but the following loop never makes it to the second print.                         'for url in urls:
      r = Render(url)
      html = r.frame.toHtml()
      print (url)'

Comment: Can you add a few more prints to see where exactly it gets stuck?

Comment: QFont::setPixelSize: Pixel size <= 0 (0) will display in the first loop, I'll get my outputs:17.1:9 (10:15)  ...17.2:14 (218 reps).... and I can make it print the second address so I know it's entering the loop it just won't make the pull from the page.